# Can I add a new attribute to some documents with mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I wanted to know if It is possible to add  a new attribute in some documents of a collection using mongoose? As with mongoose we define a schema initially, is this possible? Or we have to add the new attribute in all documents?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option for schemas called `strict`, which is turned on by default. If `strict` is turned on then Mongoose will reject properties that are not in the schema when saving. [Here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) is the documentation for `strict`. It warns you about turning it off:

> NOTE: do not set to false unless you have good reason.

I would suggest adding the property to the schema instead, with `required: false`. For documents that don't have the property, you can simply leave it undefined when saving the document. That will keep it out of the document.